# Unable to find published angular app on github pages

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I'm getting 404 upon publishing my angular 2 APP on github pages even though angular-cli-gpages says "It's successfully published"

What could be the issue?

[image]

UPDATE: After quite some times, I think the app is published now. However, there are several 404 console errors. SO only index.html seems to have published:

```
GET https://wickedrahul.github.io/polyfills.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
19:42:02.408 wickedrahul.github.io/:17 GET https://wickedrahul.github.io/inline.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
19:42:02.408 wickedrahul.github.io/:17 GET https://wickedrahul.github.io/styles.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
19:42:02.412 wickedrahul.github.io/:17 GET https://wickedrahul.github.io/vendor.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
19:42:02.415 wickedrahul.github.io/:17 GET https://wickedrahul.github.io/main.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
19:42:03.443 wickedrahul.github.io/:17 GET https://wickedrahul.github.io/polyfills.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
19:42:03.515 wickedrahul.github.io/:17 GET https://wickedrahul.github.io/styles.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
19:42:03.590 wickedrahul.github.io/:17 GET https://wickedrahul.github.io/vendor.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
19:42:03.673 wickedrahul.github.io/:17 GET https://wickedrahul.github.io/main.bundle.js 404 ()
```

Answer (score 1):

[#Feature Request : ng build to include a --base-href](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1064)

You would check this issue which said feature request in past year.Despite a year ago, it isn't implented.

So far , the `angular-cli-ghpages` module is be created.You need installed then do it!

```
npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages
npm run deploy  //- it would support your --base-href command
```